# Group data by columns and show all rows that meet criteria

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, textjoin

This is my data:

```
ID  DATA1  DATA2  DATA3  DATA4
1   yes    yes           yes
2          yes    yes
3   yes                  yes
```

What I like to get:

```
DATA1
- ID1
- ID3
DATA2
- ID1
- ID2
DATA3
- ID2
DATA4
- ID1
- ID3
```

Anyone knows what query or formula I can use for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("♦", 1, TRANSPOSE({B1:E1;
 IF(B2:E="yes", "- "&A1&A2:A, )})), "♦")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Great! Thx again player0!!